# Trouble with Numbered matching groups & Replacement

Tags: php, regex

OK, so here's the deal...

I'm trying to parse this :

```
[time_zone] => [[Central European Time|CET]]
[utc_offset] => +1
[time_zone_DST] => [[Central European Summer Time|CEST]]
[utc_offset_DST] => +2
[drives_on] => right
[calling_code] => [[Telephone numbers in Italy|39]]
[cctld] => [[.it]]
```

In brief, I'm trying to replace `[[X]]` with `X` and `[[Anything|X]]` with `X`.

And this is the regex I've come up with :

```
(?:\[\[(?:[^\|]+)\|([^\|\]]+)\]\])|\[\[(.+)?\]\]
```

Which, seemingly, does the trick fine.

So, I'm thinking of doing it like :

```
preg_replace("/$mypattern/","$1",$mystring);
```

However, here's the catch :

When matching `[[X]]`, the captured group is `$2`.
While, on the other case, it's `$1`.

What's the most elegant way of resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... As usual, I came up with a solution, seconds after I had already posted the question here in SO... lol.

So, the solution is to just change the Regex (and yep, now the captured group is always `$1`) - **UPDATED** :

```
\[\[(?:(?:[^\]]+)?\|)?([^\]]+)?\]\]
```

**P.S.** I'd still be interested to know if there is a workaround for the regex above (I mean *without* having to alter it, and/or resort to complex `preg_match_all` things, etc)

Comment: You can still use `$1$2` for the replace. One of the two will be empty, but that's no problem at all.

Comment: @Jerry Ahaa... Well, that definitely makes some sense! :-)

Comment: You may also use `trim` to strip leading and trailing characters (however, it will strip one or more characters and you may desire exactly 2). `preg_replace('/^.+\|/', '', trim($string, '[]'))`.